# Get Uid from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to find the uid from firebase. Let's say I have 3 users in my database, and I want to find the 3rd user uid.

[image: photo of firebase dashbord]

Here is json formate witch is just export from firebase:

```
{
  "-KVKrXu70Ziw0iRw46l5" : {
    "age" : 20,
    "emailId" : "ameerhamza",
    "name" : "hamza"
  },
  "-KVKrkVy5OojpsSUEI24" : {
    "age" : 20,
    "emailId" : "ameerhamza",
    "name" : "hamza"
  },
  "-KVKrkzXy9duyiZq5bM0" : {
    "age" : 21,
    "emailId" : "ameerhamzaaaa",
    "name" : "hamza"
  },
  "-KVKrl5Ax7ptodMYywzg" : {
    "age" : 22,
    "emailId" : "ameerhamza",
    "name" : "hamza"
  },
  "-KVKrr7E6b4-3x6tuwOX" : {
    "age" : 23,
    "emailId" : "ameerhamza",
    "name" : "hamza"
  },
  "-KVKruES01regClm6tWW" : {
    "age" : 24,
    "emailId" : "ameerhamza",
    "name" : "hamza"
  }
}
```

Here is code what I done. But it is not working for me.

```
 final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();
       DatabaseReference newRef = myRef.push();
          i++;
                    Student s = new Student("ameerhamza",i,"hamza");
                    newRef.child(newRef.getKey()).setValue(s);
                    final Query queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("emailId").equalTo("ameerhamzaaaa");

                 queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         Log.d("Firebase UID ",dataSnapshot.getKey());//it always null 
                         Student s = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);



                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                     }
                 });
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen i just update the my Question please help me i trying this last 2days but still noting happed

Comment: How are you referencing to your firebase database. Where is your firebase database URL?

Comment: final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Comment: bro can you check age code i just update my Q

Comment: There is no URL in the code to your firebase database project. The URL of your firebase database. If you dont provide it how can your code grab data from your database. I think you need specify URL. I have worked with firebase long ago. Not really sure I am right. Kindly ignore if i am wrong. Please go to your firebase console and copy the url and put it in getreference(i think not Really sure) method.

Comment: 'FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferencefromUrl(xxxxxxxx);'

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an extra child and you're searching within the parent. Try something like this:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference newRef = myRef.push();

i++;
Student s = new Student("ameerhamza",i,"hamza");
newRef.setValue(s);

myRef
  .orderByChild("emailId")
  .equalTo("ameerhamzaaaa")
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 Map<String, Student> data = dataSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Student>>() {});
                 Map.Entry<String, Student> entry = data.entrySet().iterator().next();
                 String uid = entry.getKey();
                 Student s = entry.getValue();
                 Log.d("Firebase UID ", uid);
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                 // handle error
             }
  });
```

It probably doesn't give you the exact id but should give you a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: bro i already try your mathod but it seems like not work for me

Comment: Probably because the current structure of your Firebase storage is still using the double keys.

Comment: Try again using the data you updated your question with and the updated code in my answer.

Comment: bro its not woking for but you show me right driction to me

Answer (score 0):

All Right fox after so much hard work, finaly i get my ANS , **Here is how i get the UID from firebase**, i **use the** Firebase Recyler Adapter to get Data From firebase and next you see your self what i done

```
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Student, myViewHolader>(


            Student.class,R.layout.item_row,myViewHolader.class,myRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(myViewHolader viewHolder, Student model, int position) {

            Log.e("myFirebase UID",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```